# Why do I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find elements when the XPath is null error message

Tags: java, selenium, error-handling

I have created a xpath.properties file and stored it at the location only. The format is as:

```
objuserName=//input[@placeholder='Username']
objpassword=//input[@placeholder='Password']
objloginButton=//a[@onclick='return ValidateLogin()']
```

Written a code to load this property file and enter the username and password and click login button. The code opens the browser successfully but on entering the username it gives "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find elements when the XPath is null."

```
public class Login {
static Properties objprop = new Properties();

static void PropertyManager() throws IOException{
    File file = new File("C:\\proj-Automation\\financialsys\\abcd\\src\\test\\resources\\xpath.properties");
    FileInputStream fileInput = null;
    try{
        fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    }
    Properties objprop = new Properties();
    try{
        objprop.load(fileInput);
    }catch(IOException e){
        }
//objprop.load(objfile);
}

//When user opens the "firefox" browser
void OpenBrowser(String browsername) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",config.getParameterValue("chrome_driver_exe_path_32bit"));
    config.driver=new ChromeDriver();
}
public void EnterUserName(String username){
    config.driver.findElement(By.xpath(objprop.getProperty("objuserName"))).sendKeys(username);

}
public void PageMaximise(){
    config.driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
//code for entering the password and clicking on login button
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Login LF = new Login();
    Login.PropertyManager();
    LF.OpenBrowser("CH32");
    LF.EnterURL("http://localhost:90/financialsys");
    LF.PageMaximise();
    LF.EnterUserName("dummycfo");
    LF.EnterPassword("passw0rd");
    LF.ClickLoginButton();
}
}
```

What could be the reason of the IllegalArgumentException error at line     config.driver.findElement(By.xpath(objprop.getProperty("objuserName"))).sendKeys(username); 
and 
LF.EnterUserName("dummycfo");

Comment: Are you loading the file successfully? You catch an ignore an IOException -- never do that -- if you are going to catch an exception and not rethrow an exception, at least log an error message.

Comment: I guess it is not able to pick the property "objuserName" from Property File which is making the XPath as null. Can u use a debugger and check that?

Comment: You should spend some time learning to use the debugger in your IDE. Set a break point early and step through your code and look at the state of the variables at each step. Then you'll see where the error is.

Comment: I changed the code to an easier one: static Properties objprop = new Properties();
  public static FileInputStream fileInput = null;
  static void propManager() throws IOException {
   fileInput = new FileInputStream("C:\\ejagruti-Automation\\mm_finsys\\ejagruti\\src\\test\\resources\\xpath.properties");
objprop.load(fileInput);                                                                            and it worked. Though the same error is shown in another module

Answer (score 1):

```
static void PropertyManager() throws IOException{
    File file = new File("C:\\proj-Automation\\financialsys\\abcd\\src\\test\\resources\\xpath.properties");
    FileInputStream fileInput = null;
    try{
        fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    }
    try{
        objprop.load(fileInput);
    }catch(IOException e){
        }
//objprop.load(objfile);
}
remove Properties objprop = new Properties(); this line from the above method, you are initializing objprop variable with a new object, instead of using the global one which you already have on the top.
```

Comment: I changed the PropertyManager code. static Properties objprop = new Properties(); public static FileInputStream fileInput = null;
 static void propManager() throws IOException {
  fileInput = new FileInputStream("C:\\ejagruti-Automation\\mm_finsys\\ejagruti\\src\\test\\resources\\xpath.properties");
   objprop.load(fileInput);
 }    It works well for the above code however for the other page the xpath is again returned as null.config.driver.findElement(By.name(objprop.getProperty("Company"))).click(); Do I have any other option than using getProperty?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try the below code to fetch the key from property file by below code snippet:

```
public static String fetchLocatorValue(String key) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(Path of perperty file);
    Properties property = new Properties();
    property.load(file);
    return property.getProperty(key).toString();

}
```